# How to enable language support for CJK languages in java?

Tags: java, fonts

I am struggling with a language problem in java server.
The java server don't recognizes some characters.

E.g.
あアｱ中表鷗㊞屢ポŒéÜßäåæðëöàùªñUGD  is represented as:  □ □ □ □ □ □ □ □ □ŒéÜßäåæðëöàùªñUGD

So at first I thought this is a problem with the operating system (suse 11) locale settings, but it is not, because I created a file with this test input string and the OS recognizes all the characters.

> After some hours in the Oracle website under [fonts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/intl/font.html)  I read the
>   following:
>
> "Note that of the writing systems that are generally fully supported
>   by the JRE, the Lucida fonts do not support Chinese (Simplified),
>   Chinese (Traditional), Japanese, and Korean." ... in Java

Additional notes: 
Installed java version: java version "1.8.0_151"

Installed fonts in /usr/java/jre-vmware/lib/fonts:
LucidaBrightDemiBold.ttf, LucidaBrightItalic.ttf,   LucidaSansDemiBold.ttf  LucidaTypewriterBold.ttf,     fonts.dir,
LucidaBrightDemiItalic.ttf,  LucidaBrightRegular.ttf,  LucidaSansRegular.ttf,   LucidaTypewriterRegular.ttf

> So my question is: how can I enable support for CJK languages (Chinese
>   (Simplified), Chinese (Traditional), Japanese, and Korean) in java?

Comment: most likely suspect: encoding